# How to add libraries to target with maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I want to run Docker container on my machine. It's a Spring boot application written on Java.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD target/task-service.jar /app/task-service.jar
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8090
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-classpath", "task-service.jar", "com/company/TasksServiceStarter"]
```

When I run, I have an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
at com.company.TasksServiceStarter.main(TasksServiceStarter.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

I use `maven-jar-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Manifest file in jar looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven Jar Plugin 3.2.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 11
Class-Path: lib/spring-web-5.3.7.jar lib/spring-beans-5.3.7.jar lib/spri
 ng-core-5.3.7.jar lib/spring-jcl-5.3.7.jar lib/spring-boot-starter-web-
 2.5.0.jar lib/spring-boot-starter-2.5.0.jar lib/spring-boot-2.5.0.jar l
 ib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-
 2.5.0.jar lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar lib/
 log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar lib/log4j-api-2.14.1.jar lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7
 .30.jar lib/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar lib/snakeyaml-1.28.jar lib
 /spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.0.jar lib/jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar lib
 /jackson-annotations-2.12.3.jar lib/jackson-core-2.12.3.jar lib/jackson
 -datatype-jdk8-2.12.3.jar lib/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.3.jar lib/ja
 ckson-module-parameter-names-2.12.3.jar lib/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-
 2.5.0.jar lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar lib/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.46.j
 ar lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.46.jar lib/spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar li
 b/spring-aop-5.3.7.jar lib/spring-context-5.3.7.jar lib/spring-expressi
 on-5.3.7.jar lib/modelmapper-2.4.1.jar lib/postgresql-42.2.20.jar lib/c
 hecker-qual-3.5.0.jar lib/lombok-1.18.20.jar lib/mybatis-spring-boot-st
 arter-2.1.4.jar lib/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.5.0.jar lib/HikariCP-4.0
 .3.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar lib/spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar lib/spring-tx
 -5.3.7.jar lib/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar lib/mybatis-
 3.5.6.jar lib/mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar lib/
 jersey-client-2.29.jar lib/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar lib/jersey-commo
 n-2.33.jar lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar lib/jakarta.inject-2.5.0
 .jar
```

How can I fix a bug?

Comment: you would need to use the plugin of spring-boot to build a jar, not the standard jar plugin. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html

Comment: You don't need to do anything special, let Spring Boot build the jar and place it in a container. or even better just let Spring handle all that for you. Remove your jar plugin and run `mvn spring-boot:build-image` and you will get an optimized Spring Boot docker image.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using spring-boot, then instead of normal packaging, you can create a shaded jar:

```
mvn package shade:shade
```

This jar will be bigger than your normal jar. Use this with your docker container.

<sub>PS: have used `spring-boot-maven-plugin` here</sub>

Comment: You should be using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. If you use the shade plugin you will also have to change how to boot your Spring Boot application.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've mentioned that here that I'm using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in the last line. And regarding the changes, OP will have to make changes as per their application.

Comment: Spring Boot automatically creates a fat jar, running `shade:shade` will not help.